# how to access the files of Nested folders in Skydrive API?

Tags: objective-c, onedrive

```
NSArray *arr = [[operation.result objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
NSArray *arrId = [[operation.result objectForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"id"];
NSArray *folder=[[operation.result objectForKey:@"data"]valueForKey:@"type"];
[dictDocument setObject:arrId forKey:@"ID"];
[dictDocument setObject:arr forKey:@"Name"];
[dictDocument setObject:folder forKey:@"type"];
```

Arrid===>folder.id,file.id

arr===>filename

folder====>type of file Eg.Folder,audio,video
I can't able to access the files of nested folders??

Answer (score 0):

try like this,and once check in copy bundle identifiers files are added succeessfully or not.

```
    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"vid" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
    avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    avPlayer.delegate = self;
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];
```

[image]

FOR PLAYING VEDIO

You can use MPMoviePlayerController to play local file.

[refer this one for playing vedio file.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802403/how-to-play-local-video-file)

Comment: :Thanks for the reply.But I want to play a video file not the audio help me

Comment: then use MPVedioPlayer class for playing vedios,

Comment: @send2me:once check my last part of the answer you'l find something related to playing vedio file.