# macos - Play video with minimum CPU and memory. AVPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone

How to play a local video file with minimum CPU and memory？

Is the AVPlayer Framework？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrate local video play by AVPlayer is not big deal but you should integrate properly. Please refer following thing and conform what you missing.

`objective-c`
[how to play local video file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802403/how-to-play-local-video-file)

`swift`
[How to play a local video with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25348877/how-to-play-a-local-video-with-swift)

Comment: The platform is macos, not iOS. There is no AVPlayerViewController and MPMoviePlayerController in macos.